# Displaying Star Image According Integer In Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a star ratings feature. And pretty much, I would like it to display a particular image depending on the number.

Here's some pseduo code I would like to do in my review.rb model

```
def show_stars
  if rating = 1
    display 1star.png
  elsif rating = 2
    display 2star.png
  elsif rating = 3
    display 3star.png
  elsif rating = 4
    display 4star.png
  elsif rating = 5
    display 5star.png
end
```

How would I make this code work? And also, how would I make it display right in a view file?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: hey Sergio, I updated and put a question at the end. Code currently doesn't work.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't work. You need changes in your controller, view etc. Go get a rails book and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should really go into a view helper.

```
def show_stars(review)
  image_tag "#{review.rating}star.png"
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= show_stars @review %>
```